# How to identify a txt file and non text file and add TRUE/FALSE in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am a beginner to powerShell and wanted to find a solution for the below issue. Need your advise on this.

The requirement is

1. There is a parent and Child folder that contains different type of file extension like txt, pss, sql etc.
2. If the PS finds the txt file in either of Parent or Child Folder, then it need to add a column as TRUE.
3. If the PS finds any other file apart from txt file, it need to mark it as False.

Note: I tried using the below command

Get-ChildItem -path  - Recurse

I was able to list all the files with its extension.

I am stuck at how to add the TRUE or False part. Kindly advise on this. Thanks much for all your time.

Comment: May I ask what a 'Unix' file is? Do you mean a file without file type, i.e. .txt ? 
Besides, what did you try so far to achieve your objective? You should look into the function `Get-ChildItem`.

Comment: Are you talking about _executable_ files? Like, ELF binaries vs PE binaries?

Comment: Mathias,

Just trying to figure out that anything other than windows need to be marked as False. It can be any file type like sql job etc...basically any file other than txt file is False.

Comment: Alex, Yes I tried Get - ChildItem. But i m not getting the desired result. Basically any file other than windows file have to return False.

Comment: UNIX and Windows don't really mean anything, so what are you currently using to tell which is which? Files that can be opened with notepad? Files with no default program assigned? Text encoding? Mime-types? Line endings (CRLF/LF)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your edit says you want to find .TXT files in a folder. Try using the `-Filter` on `Get-ChildItem`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Filter *.txt
```

To get all files with the True/False you're looking for, you could try a calculated property with `Select-Object`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\temp" -Recurse |
  Select-Object @{l='TXT';e={$_.Extension -eq '.txt'}},FullName

# Output looks like:

  TXT FullName                                                                                     
  --- --------
False C:\temp\temp.csv                                                                             
False C:\temp\test.csv                                                                             
 True C:\temp\temp.txt                                                                         
 True C:\temp\test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Cpt.Whale, this is exactly i am looking.

But whenever i execute this Select-Object I am getting "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Object'.  Kindly advise where i am going wrong ?

Comment: @KameshA Please add your entire command. Maybe you have `Select Object` instead of `Select-Object`?

Comment: Please find the details:

PS H:\Desktop> Get-ChildItem -path "H:\Desktop\Parent_Folder" -Recurse | Select -Object @{1='TXT';e={$_.Extension -eq '.txt'}},Fullname
Select-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Object'.
At line:1 char:66
+ ... em -path "H:\Desktop\Parent_Folder" -Recurse | Select -Object @{1='TX ...
+                                                           ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :

Comment: @KameshA `Select-Object` is a single command name. No spaces

Comment: excellant and thank a lot. I will mark this case as resolved.